# How to get values of user defined variables from a database?

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

This is my first SSIS project and I have been told to get values for all variables in a package from SQL SERVER table which has variable name and their values. I am not able to find any tutorial which can show me how to get values from SQL Server database table and assign them to the SSIS user defined variable.

How can I get variable values from table and assign to the variable? I have around 20 variable in my package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for how to use *Package Configurations* within SSIS package. Package configuration enables you to store the values of the user defined variables outside of the package so that you don't have to alter the package when only the variable values need to be changed. You can store the values in a database table or XML based configuration file or environment variables and there are other options too.

Following links might help you to understand how to use package configuration within SSIS packages:

[**Understanding Integration Services Package Configurations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx)

[**Package Configurations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx)